# How to implement bidirectional hibernate relationship correctly?

Tags: sql, spring, hibernate, one-to-one

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "project")
public class Project {

@Id
@Column(name = "project_id")
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
private int id;

@OneToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "idea_id", referencedColumnName = "idea_id")
@JsonIgnore
private Idea idea; .......}
```

And

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "idea")
public class Idea {

@Id
@Column(name = "idea_id")
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
private int id;

@Size(max = 240)
@NotNull
private String description;

@OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
@JoinColumn(name = "project_id", referencedColumnName = "project_id")
private Project project; ..........}
```

What is wrong with my hibernate relationships in these two classes? This is example of relationship that I want to implement. [image: Database model]

And this is actual tables that I get with these relationships:

Idea table:
[image: Idea table]

And Project table:

[image: Project table]

How to get rid of null values in idea_id column in project table?

Comment: You don't need two foreign keys for a single association. Either you choose project.idea_id to  referened the PK of the idea table, or you choose idea.project_id to reference the PK of the project table. But not both. One side must be the inverse of the other, as explained in the documentation: https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/current/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#associations-one-to-one-bidirectional

Comment: The keyword in the OneToOne annotation would be „mappedBy“.